# Burning an open channel in DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, raster-calculator, hydrology

I need to burn a DEM surface to generate an open channel. (all dimensions and slopes are known)
I thought I should use raster calculator to subtract a raster represent channel depths from the DEM raster. but there is only one matter, the land surface is varied and hence I don’t know where the channel side slopes will intersect with the DEM.
Is there a function to find the intersection line between two rasters (channel side slope and DEM)

[image]

Comment: You need to know heights at the channel ends as well

Comment: Yes, I have elevation at both ends of the channels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already rasterized your channel depths, try simply running a minimum function (or a Conditional statement) to merge them together properly:

```
Con(ChannelRas < DEM, ChannelRas, DEM)
```

Comment: If you are going to rasterize an open channel (if you have all nodes coordinates), will you use all the data in rasterizing, or will you rasterize each side (bottom, right side, left side) separately?.
I have tried both earlier and I found the second choice gives better results.

Comment: I would think that the ideal option for rasterization might depend on the density of input data relative to output raster resolution. It will ultimately depend on data resolution/precision expectations and your ability to model the true channel morphology of your participation study area.

Comment: Also, if you're satisfied with my answer to your original question, it might be best to mark it as "answered" to help the greater community moving forward.